# Oracle SQL: How to eliminate redundant recursive calls in CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

The below set represents the sales of a product in consecutive weeks.

```
22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17
```

...
    weekly sales table

```
date        sales
week-1 :    22
week-2 :    19 
week-3 :    20 
... 
week-12 :   10
week-13 :   17
```

I need to find the longest run of higher sales figures for consecutive weeks, i.e week-6 to week-11 represented by `14,15,15,18,21,24`.

I am trying to use a recursive CTE to move forward to the next week(s) to find if the sales value is equal or higher. As long as the value is equal or higher, keep on moving to the next week, recording the ROWNUMBER of the anchor member (represents the starting week number) and the week number of the iterated row. With this approach, there are redundant recursive calls. For example, when cte is called for week-2, it iterates week-3, week-4 and week-5 as the sales values are higher on each week from its previous week. Now, after week-2, the cte should be called for week-5 as week-3, week-4 and week-5 have already been visited.

Basically, if I have already visited a row of `filt_coll` in my recursive calls, I do not want it to be passed to the CTE again. The rows marked as redundant should not be found and the values for `actualweek` column should be unique.

I know the sql below does not give a solution to my problem of finding the longest run of higher values. I can work out that from the max count of `startweek` column. For now, I am trying to figure out how to eliminate the redundant recursive calls.

```
START_WEEK | SALES | SALESLAG | SALESLEAD | ACTUALWEEK    
1          | 22   | 0     | -3            | 1
2          | 19   | -3    | 1             | 2
2          | 20   | 1     | 3             | 3
2          | 23   | 3     | -7            | 4
3          | 20   | 1     | 3             | 3 <-(redundant)
3          | 23   | 3     | -7            | 4 <-(redundant)
4          | 23   | 3     | -7            | 4 <-(redundant)
6          | 14   | -2    | 1             | 6
```

...

```
with 
-- begin test data 
raw_data (sales) as
(
  select '22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17' from dual
)
,
derived_tbl(week, sales) as
(
  select level, regexp_substr(sales, '([[:digit:]]+)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from raw_data connect by level <= regexp_count(sales,',')+1
)
-- end test data
,
coll(week, sales, saleslag, saleslead) as
(
  select week, sales, 
    nvl(sales - (lag(sales) over (order by week)), 0), 
    nvl((lead(sales) over (order by week) - sales), 0)
  from derived_tbl
)
,
filt_coll(week, sales, saleslag, saleslead) as
(
  select week, sales, saleslag, saleslead 
  from coll 
  where not (saleslag < 0 and saleslead < 0)
)
,
cte(startweek, sales, saleslag, saleslead, actualweek) as
(
  select week, sales, saleslag, saleslead, week from filt_coll 
  -- where week not in (select week from cte)
  -- *** want to achieve the effect of the above commented out line
  union all
  select cte.startweek, cl.sales, cl.saleslag, cl.saleslead, cl.week 
  from filt_coll cl, cte
  where cl.week = cte.actualweek + 1 and cl.sales >= cte.sales
)
select * from cte 
order by 1,actualweek
;
```

Comment: What does your `dummy` column (or the query itself) have to do with the question you have asked?  Perhaps you should ask *another* question and clarify what you really want to do.  For instance, given your data, how do you define "consecutive rows"?